# SyncSharedMemory - how to relsease the object and memory

Tags: php

Can the [SyncSharedMemory](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.syncsharedmemory.php) be used in production environments?

Why can't we find any definition of destroy or release methods?

The same as [SyncReaderWriter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.syncreaderwriter.php), Unable to find any definition for releasing resources.

```php
class SyncSharedMemory {
    public __construct(string $name, int $size)
    public first(): bool
    public read(int $start = 0, int $length = ?)
    public size(): int
    public write(string $string = ?, int $start = 0)
}
```

Comment: the idea is to have objects variables or functions to be used across processes. for that to work the objects have to exit before a thread tries to access it, so they exist as long the webserve with the extension runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove any references by setting the instance to null.

```
$instance = new SyncSharedMemory('test', 100);
$instance = null;
```

Then, when the garbage collector will run, it will release it.

You can [force to collect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles) earlier by calling, but you should avoid that.

```
gc_collect_cycles();
```

Comment: How do we share the memory among multiple processes if it always releases automatically?

Comment: It is shared as long as at least one process is running. Quote: `Shared memory goes away when the last reference to it disappears.` from https://www.php.net/manual/en/syncsharedmemory.construct.php